# Retrieve all emails with fail status from smtp

Tags: c#, smtp

Is there any way to fetch all the failed mails in the smtp server, after the actual send of the mail.

My problem is that I need to know if the mail is failed after queue for sending. For an example if I try to send from my email account an email to valid email address, but not existing.

Known solution in the web is working with the bounced emails. So log in into the account from where I send the mail, find the bounced email and find the failed mail. After that you do whatever you want.

Could I find all the emails on smtp level ? I need to make this check for all accounts. So is any command to find failed mails into the smtp ?

Comment: SMTP is only for mail **transmission**. It would be a gigantic security flaw if you could query servers for information using SMTP

Comment: @Liam the specification includes queries, such as user lookup. Most SMTP servers don't give anything away if you use these queries though for the reason you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMTP server that you send you mails from is unlikely to know that the mail has failed. Once it has successfully passed the mail onto the next server the communication is over and it has no knowledge of what happens to that email.

This is why you have to work with bounced mails, as there may be multiple SMTP message transfer agents along the path. Each of these may reject the mail for different reasons and usually only the final one will reject based on mailboxes being full, addresses not being known and so on.

The last thorny topic will be that not all servers will send notifications.

Comment: So the information that the mail failed to deliver the email message is stored in the receiver smtp server ? I suppose that my smtp server creates the bounce email, because of this exchange messages. Could I somehow retrieve them ?

Comment: From what I read in wikipedia the bounce message can be create by own mail server and by the receiver so you are correct.